# MongoDB: Store data from collection additionally as embedded documents in another collection

Tags: mongodb, schema, database, nosql

In MongoDB does it make sense to embed some data of a document from one collection additionally in the documents of another collection?

Let's say I have an application that stores bookmarks that people can annotate with one or more tags to query them. So one bookmark can have multiple tags and one tag can be referenced in multiple bookmarks (n:m).

Now for fast read operations I decide to de-normalize the data and embed the tags directly inside the bookmarks collection. But what if I also need to access a list of all tags for other purposes of the application? Does it make sense to expose the tags as an own collection and not use a DBRef inside the bookmark documents but instead store some of the tag data directly (i.e. only the id and name of the tag)?

Does this perform better than using DBRefs? Are there any other downsides apart from the redundancy? Would that make sense at all? :-)

Comment: Dbrefs don't do anything. Some drivers will automatically load the data via additional queries to the DB. So, yes, it could perform better. If data or tag names can be changed centrally you'll need to consider that complexity.

Comment: What if I embed the tags only inside the bookmarks collection. How can I efficiently query for a list of all tags (without duplicates)?

Comment: If tags are indexed, you could use the aggregation framework to query and group on tag names. Or, you could run a MapReduce.  Or, you could just store them in a Tags collection that your code maintains. The latter could be very efficient.

Comment: In your third option do you mean the way I described it in my question: Maintain an additional list of all tags as a separate collection?

Comment: Yes.  If you only use one document and cache tags in memory assuming they all fit in 16MB or less, it could be very efficient. At least cache them either way.

Comment: If I use multiple documents in the tags collection instead of only one do you have a rough guess how bad it will inflict on performance? The problem is that any user can create his own tags and in theory that could be an infinite number. So I think I can't store all tags of all users in one document. Maybe I could create one document per user, which will then contain all the tags of this user.

Comment: No, I don't have an estimate -- there's no way to estimate it with such little information.

Comment: Okay one more question :-) If I decide to store the list of all tags as a separate collection would it make a difference when I do not create an extra collection tags, but store the list of all tags of an user as embedded data in the user collection (which I alread have). When the user info is queried (i.e. for authentication) I would normally exclude the tags and only include them when a request is explicitly looking for the list of all tags.

Comment: It's up to you, your data model, and your requirements, as there's no technical reason it wouldn't work.

Comment: Allright! Thank you very much for all your answers :)